# How to organize multiple solutions in one TFS project

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I am new to VS Team Foundation Server 2015 and there I have project for example "WebProjectA". I also have MVC .NET Project called "WebProjectA".
How to manage that project in TFS when I have 3 environments (Development, Testing, Production) ?

Need I have 3 TFS Projects

- WebProjectA_Development
- WebProjectA_Testing
- WebProjectA_Production

Or can I place all WebProjectA solutions to one VS workspace or 3 workspaces and somehow to link it to the TFS and have version system enabled per solution in one TFS project ?

How do you solve this situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle this using a TFS branching structure.  Create a single Team Project, called WebProjectA, and a single branch called Testing.  Then, branch off for Development, and again for Production.  This means that, when you make a change in development, you can merge through to testing, and again into production.

[image: Diagram]

It also gives you the flexibility to switch to feature branching at a later date, and to maintain multiple production branches, should you wish to.

[Further reading](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/branch-strategically)

Comment: Thank you I got it, in source code I found options to manage the branches but I have one more question, if I already have WebProjectA which is versioned in TFS but in no branch how can I move this project to WebProjectA/Main Branch with preservation of the existing commits ?

Comment: I believe that you can use TFS Power Tools to convert your existing folder (assuming that's what you have) to a branch: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1

Comment: I already create a branch from the project but i dont know how to move that branch under the project I created branch from.. maybe I will need to create new project and merge existing branch to the new branch hierarchy, it is a good idea ?